# Can domainA read cookies from domainB using the script on domainB?

Tags: javascript, cookies

The read cookie script is on domainB, and in domainA I have page that references that script on domainB, in this case, is it possible to read the cookie set from domainB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set domain for particular domain...ie on domainA you can have script

```
document.cookie = "name1=value1;domain=.domainA.com;path=/";
document.cookie = "name1=value1;domain=.domainB.com;path=/";
```

and both domain can access cookie name1.